# optimize my query doctrine symfony

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to optimize my query.

it take really so slow, it take more than 50 secondes to get result :-(

i have more than 120 000 data.

here is my query

```
$q = $this->_em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM AppBundle:Cabinne c JOIN AppBundle:Rdv r WITH c.id NOT 
    IN  (SELECT us.id FROM  AppBundle:Rdv rv JOIN rv.cabinne_id us  JOIN us.centre cee 
    WHERE  (rv.dateRdv >= :start AND rv.dateRdv < :enddate  AND  rv.etat = :etat ) 
    OR (rv.dateRdv <= :start AND rv.DateFin > :start  AND  rv.etat = :etat ) 
    OR (rv.dateRdv < :start AND rv.DateFin > :enddate  AND  rv.etat = :etat ) AND cee.id = :id )  JOIN c.centre ceee WHERE  ceee.id = :id ");


    $q->setParameter('start', $start);
    $q->setParameter('enddate', $end);
    $q->setParameter('etat', 1);
    $q->setParameter('id', $id);
```

can someone help please 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: Paginate and get only the first 10 resutls.

---

Otherwise I hope you are trying to do that on a background processing. If not you have something else to optimize instead of the query.

1) I'm sure this code executes extremely fast ~2ms as you are not executing the query. Add the full code please.

2) Did you use the symfony profiler or mysql log slow queries and check the query generated? How long it takes to run that query without doctrine? Which is the RDMS execution plan add describe in the front of the SQL (not DQL)?

3) Probably your biggest issue is how you handle the data on the doctrine hydrator. Try to see how much time is spend during the hydrator with xdebug profiling. Is hydrator what it slows down your query?

---

If the problem is the query time. You may need to create a database view and some indexes. The RDMS execution plan will show you where it is the problem.

If your problem is on the hydrator you can try to return an iterator and iterate the results with an on demand hydrator.